# Ios gcm GCM_SENDER_ID dynamic

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

How can i use dynamic `GCM_SENDER_ID`.
Logic:

- when i login, server returns me `GCM_SENDER_ID`
- then i need to register GCM with that id

but i get error 401

```
Registration to GCM failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 401.)
```

This is example:
I have 2 domains, 2 web apps, and i made 2 apps in Google Console for gcm, second app can't see push messages from first app.
Then for ios i have manager app that can connect to GCM with `GCM_SENDER_ID` from first and seccond web app, with different id.

Now i have 3 apps in google console:

- app1
- app2
- manager app(for certificates)

How can i use dynamic `GCM_SENDER_ID` for manager app?

When i login to `app1` server returns me `GCM_SENDER_ID` and then i use it to register gcm on ios, but getting that error 401.

Comment: GCM ? GCM is for Android devices(Google cloud messaging), for iOS similar service is known as APNS (Apple Push notification server)

Comment: @VaibhavGautam yes, and i connected it to gcm so i send messages from gcm to all devices

Comment: @MirzaDelic, so your `app1` and `app2` are both web app, and the `manager app` is an iOS app? If so, your `manager app` can have a different registration token, you should [unregister](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#unregistration-and-unsubscription) your `manager app` first before it registers for a new token. Also, you should paste the registration related code of your `manager app` in your question.